# MariaDB - Duplicate entry '1-652' for key 'IX1_MY_Table'

Tags: hibernate, mariadb

I am trying to update my table with following query

```
 update MY_Table set NS_LEFT = NS_LEFT + 10  where NS_THREAD = 1 and NS_LEFT > 652
```

while executing this query on MariaDb I am getting exception

> ```
> ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - (conn=194) Duplicate entry '1-652' for key 'IX1_MY_Table'
> ```

UNIQUE INDEX -

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX1_MY_Table ON MY_Table (NS_THREAD asc, NS_LEFT asc);
```

MariaDb version : 10.2.11-MariaDB

JDBC driver version  : 2.4.1

What could be the probable cause of this issue and how can I solve this, in another DB its is working as charm(In MySql too), why its failing in MariaDB only. The query I have shared is generic for all DB And really dont think the query has some issue, and also do not want to change this, I went through almost all possible thing which is suggested by different blogs but nothing worked

Please suggest some work around or fix for same

Comment: And what is the key IX1_USM_CONFIGURATION?

Comment: It is a index, kindly check updated question

Comment: So you are updating the keys of a unique index, that could clearly be an issue. Are you sure you want to to this?

Comment: Its configuration tree manipulation, yes we need it and other DB also doing this perfectly, MariaDB only giving issue.

Comment: Well I don’t have an answer but this should be easy to reproduce so you can test any solutions in an isolated environment

Comment: Possibly I have tested all suggested solution but didn't get any luck... :s

Comment: I can easily reproduce this for several dbms, like mysql, mariadb and PostgreSQL. Look at this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=1f6501723630dfcdf18de25f1682b9ac. Not with the exact same value but still.

Comment: What would be its cause ? how can I solve this?

Comment: and not reproducible in DB2, and Sqlserver  only reproduced on MySQL and MariaDB on your given link

Comment: My point with the dbfiddle was to show you that it is was easy to reproduce and that it was not only mariadb as you claimed it was. I suggest you do some more research about this issue yourself since so far most of your claims have been wrong. I don’t have anything else to contribute with anyway.

Comment: In MySQL/MariaDB, try: `UPDATE MY_Table ... AND NS_LEFT > 652 ORDER BY NS_LEFT DESC;`.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE MY_Table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query works for me

```
 UPDATE MY_Table ... AND NS_LEFT > 652 ORDER BY NS_LEFT DESC;
```

But I am still confused why we need order by in MariaDB case, but other database does supprt normal update query.